# Wordpress google map in background overlay

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

I have wordpress site. 
I want to use google map background overlay in footer.
like this [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34erpqh1zhq073l/Screenbackground.png?dl=0).
Is there any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a plugin for that, but you can do it with css:

1. Create a contanier div
2. Create the map div container
3. Create the info container

At the end you must have something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="map"></div><!-- end Map -->
    <div class="box-info">... more HTML </div>
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

Then, add some styles:

```
.wrapper{
   position: relative; // Position relative to container
   z-index: 1 // add a "level" to this div
 }
 .box-info{
   position: absolute; // Put this div on top of his parent
   z-index: 2; // Add one more "Level" to this div, so this will be on top
   top:0; 
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height: (Some height)px;
   background: ....
 }
```

You need to [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), so you can understand better some things.